# AlarmManager. Создать будильник

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Мой класс отвечающий за будильник

```
public class HelperAlarm  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final public static String ONE_TIME="onetime";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm=(PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl= pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"YOUR TAG");
//Осуществляем блокировку
        wl.acquire();

//Здесь можно делать обработку.
        Bundle extras= intent.getExtras();
        StringBuilder msgStr=new StringBuilder();

        if(extras!=null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
//проверяем параметр ONE_TIME, если это одиночный будильник,
//выводим соответствующее сообщение.
            msgStr.append("Одноразовый будильник: ");
        }
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

        Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Разблокируем поток.
        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,  HelperAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);//Задаем параметр интента
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);
//Устанавливаем интервал срабатывания в 5 секунд.
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000,pi);
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(context, HelperAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);//Отменяем будильник, связанный с интентом данного класса
    }

    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, HelperAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);//Задаем параметр интента
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    }
}
```

Я не могу понять пару вещей:

1) Почему одноразовый будильник не срабатывает сразу, а примерно через 5 секунд?

2) Многоразовый будильник работает как хочет. Первый старт примерно через 5 
секунд, далее по разному.

3) Как мне пробудить устройство? Когда срабатывает будильник нужно запустить приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Alarmmanger не гарантирует выполнение в точно установленное время. Это написано в документации.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);

            PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3, alarmPendingIntent);
```

Comment: А как мне пробудить устройство? скажите хоть что гуглить.

Comment: У Вас alarmanager посылает intent. Вы можете создать broadcastreceiver и перехватывать этот intent. от туда делать startActvity

Comment: Как я вызову startActvity не в активности? У моего класса нет такого метода.

Comment: У вас в BroadcastReceiver в метод onReceive придет контекст и пишите context.startActvity

Comment: Пробовал, вызывает ошибку. Не понимаю какой интент туда передать, с какими параметрами.

Comment: Добавил код. В класс receiver придет интент. Вот там и делайте context.startActvity